# Echarts From Baidu Bar and Line graph Issue

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have just started working on Echarts and implemented some charts. 
I have to implement a chart for a client's web site.
The problem I am encountering is that my bar's are going one behind another,
and if the value is less I cannot see the bar which is behind.

Here is my code:

```js
var provider = ['JD','JR'];
option = {
    title:{


  },
    tooltip : {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    toolbox: {
        show : true,
        feature : {
            mark : {show: true},
            dataView : {show: true, readOnly: false},
            magicType: {show: true, type: ['line', 'bar']},
            restore : {show: true},
            saveAsImage : {show: true}
        }
    },
    calculable : true,
    legend: {
        data:['2012','2013','Baseline']
    },
    xAxis : [
        {
            type : 'value',
          min :0,
          max: provider.length,
          scale: true,
          splitNumber: provider.length,
          axisLabel:{
           formatter: function(v){
              if(v!=0)
             return provider[v-1];
            else 
              return ;}
          } 

        }
    ],
    yAxis : [
        {
            type : 'value',
            name : '',
             scale:true,
     min: 0,
          max:100,
          splitNumber:10,
            axisLabel : {
                formatter: '{value}%'
            }
        },

    ],
    series : [

        {
            name:'Baseline',
            type:'line',
            data:[ [1,30],[2,10],[1,20],[2,33.33]
                    ] 
        },
       {
            name:'2012',
            type:'bar',
          barWidth: 30,
            data:[[1,35],[2,50]],

        }, 
               {
    name:'2013',
            type:'bar',
          barWidth: 30,
            data:[[1,30],[2,33.33]],
        }

    ]
};
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGhfc.png)

As you can see in the above image, that the bar's are going one behind the another on the  same xaxis point. I want to show them separately. Please help

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use set `stack` property inside the series.
If stack is having same value for two series, they'll be shown on top of each other, it makes the chart more compact and still readable.

```
series : [
    {
        name:'Baseline',
        type:'line',
        stack: 'total',
        data:[ [1,30],[2,10],[1,20],[2,33.33] ]
    },
    {
        name:'2012',
        type:'bar',
        stack: 'total',
        barWidth: 30,
        data:[[1,35],[2,50]],
    },
    {
        name:'2013',
        type:'bar',
        stack: 'total',
        barWidth: 30,
        data:[[1,30],[2,33.33]],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the x-axis to be of type `category` instead of `value`:

```
option.xAxis[0].type = 'category';
```